# slower timer for a clock

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

i want a timer that doesn't count every second. i want it to run slower

```
    timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;
    int itimer = (int)timer;
    int minutes = itimer % 60;
    int hours = itimer / 60;
    string time = hours.ToString() + ":" + minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

this is the code now. the clock currently starts at 19:20 and i want the minute counter to go up every 4 seconds or something(i still have to figure the exact timing out). i tried doing "Time.deltaTime*0.9", but the code doesn't work like that. how can i best slow it down with this code? also, when it's 20:00 (or 1200 before conversion) i'd like for something to happen, so i still need access to that number
thank you

Comment: because you are talking about `Time.deltaTime` I assume you are working with unity3d, please be sure to include the relevent tags when asking a question.

Comment: Just start a Timer that elapses ever second and have a DateTime where you store your starttime. On every timer event just call the datetime method AddMilliseconds() and add some (as many as you want) more millisencods than 1000

Comment: You said *"but the code doesn't work like that"* What happened when you tried, how was the behavior incorrect? Also @ThomasVoß this is unity, he is not talking about real wall clock time but in game time. And it is a in game time where 1 second wall clock time = 1 minute in game time.

Comment: Instead of using calculations based on how much time has passed since the last frame, wouldn't it be easier to record the real world start time, see how many seconds have passed since then, scale the number of seconds, and then convert that to a time? I guess pausing or closing the game could cause complications, so maybe not...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i'm sorry, i didn't think that was an important tag. i'll remember it for next time.
well, what happened was that the code got a red line under it, so i didn't even try executing that version. i'm able to multiply with anything equal or greater to 1. but anything smaller turns it red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the problem you had was a casting error when you tried assigning the result back to `timer`. This is because by default when you did `0.9` it did it as a `double` and your variable `timer` was a float. Add a `f` to the end of the number to mark it a float and it should work.

```
timer = timer + Time.deltaTime * 0.9f;
int itimer = (int)timer;
int minutes = itimer % 60;
int hours = itimer / 60;
string time = hours.ToString() + ":" + minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Comment: ohh!! yes! that's probably it. how could I forget about that. i feel like such a dummy for asking right now. i'm sorry for bothering anybody who read this. i should have known this